# Meaning of なんてったって

Tags: meaning

Ron tells Malfoy what's in Harry's package (Harry Potter, Japanese translation):

> 「ただの箒なんかじゃないぞ。**なんてったって**、ニンバス２０００だぜ。君、家に何持ってるって言った？ コメット２６０かい？」
> That's not just a broom. ???? It's the Nimbus 2000. What did you say you've got at home? The Comet 260?

What does なんてったって mean in this sentence? Jisho gives "no matter what", which doesn't make any sense. The [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6) definition says something similar, as far as I can tell. Although from this entry I gather it's a contraction of 何と言ったって (no matter what you say).

If I were to translate it as "no matter what you say" I could only understand it as preempting an expectation that Malfoy would refuse to believe it's a Nimbus 2000. I doubt this is the actual meaning, and there is no such nuance in the original English text.

In summary, what does なんてったって mean in this context, and how is it used more generally?

Comment: *It's the Nimbus 2000, **after all***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, なんてったって is a contraction of 何と言ったって. They both are set phrases used like "after all", "above all", "the thing is, ...", "theories aside", "first and foremost", "in any case", "at the end of the day" or something alone those lines. It's used before stating something so crucial or fundamental that saying it alone might prove something or conclude a discussion.

The literal interpretation is indeed "no matter what (else) one might say, (it's X)". But the implication here is "Since it's X after all, any further discussion is pointless" rather than "It's absolutely X no matter what".